# DB::select not preserving order

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am sending the following query to a mySQL DB:

```
select * 
from `accounts` 
    inner join `countries` on `accounts`.`country_code` = `countries`.`country_code` 
order by 
    `accounts`.`type` asc, 
    `accounts`.`sub_type` asc, 
    `countries`.`name` asc, 
    `accounts`.`name` asc
```

When executing it from a GUI client, I can see that the first 3 ids are 3,4 and 5. But when executing it using DB::select, the system returns the following ids: 3, 28 and 29.

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

When I changed the query from `select *` to `select accounts.*` the issue was solved.